# custom hook avoid race conditions

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

For educational purposes, I'm trying not to use `react-query` and trying to make a basic implementation of something similar.

I'm trying to figure out how to add the returned cleanup callback to avoid race conditions explained [here](https://beta-reactjs-org-git-you-might-not-fbopensource.vercel.app/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#fetching-data) but I can't figure out how to work it in to my below hook.

When I try to add it, it prevents the first load from ever loading b/c I think the component using this hook is re-rendering before the first request has finished.

```js
  const {
    isLoading,
    data: launches,
    error,
    refresh,
  } = usePromise('oneLaunch', () => getLaunchById(id));
```

```js
export const usePromise = (label, callbackThatMakesAPromise) => {
  const [cache, setCache] = useState(new Map());
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (cache.has(label)) {
        // Avoid infinite loop since component using this may not be
        // using useCallback on the callbackThatMakesAPromise
        return;
      }

      setIsLoading(true);
      console.log(`usePromise is loading ${label}`);

      callbackThatMakesAPromise()
        .then((res) => setData(res))
        .catch((err) => setError(err))
        .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));

      cache.set(label, true);
    },
    // Rerun if these change.
    [label, callbackThatMakesAPromise, cache]
  );

  return {
    data,
    error,
    isError: !!error,
    isLoading,
    refresh: () => {
      const updatedCache = new Map(cache);
      // allow the a request to go through when this state change triggers reload.
      updatedCache.delete(label);
      setCache(updatedCache);
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what did you try to return from useEffect. But I read example from your link and I think that you can try to use useRef. It allows to save data between re-renders and does not call re-render by itself because it's not mutable.

Comment: As in all React, the caller needs to provide a referentially stable callback. A hook shouldn't have to worry about trying to determine if the caller is making a mistake. Then you can use the same code in the link you posted to cancel any stale fetches.

Comment: @windowsill from what I have heard other libs like react query don’t require the component to pass in a memorized callback so I’m wondering how that can be avoided to make it easier on the caller to use this.